# What version stability guarantees does Alpine provide (if any)?

Tags: alpine-linux

I was surprised to see that Alpine upgraded the CVS package recently as part of a "security patch" from CVS version 1.11.23 to 1.12.12, even in the old "stable" Alpine branch 3.11 (aports update https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/main/cvs?h=3.11-stable&id=8cdd93154aeb43702a196270e3818bf2466c3e0c). This broke a legacy application for me, which is only compatible with CVS 1.11.x.

I am trying to figure out what approach alpine takes to version stability in general. Can one assume that software in an alpine release (e.g., 3.11) remains stable except for bugfixes? (This would mean that changing from CVS 1.11 to CVS 1.12 was a maintainer mistake). Or do I have to be prepared as an Alpine user to software versions changing arbitrarily (in this case, it's hard to build stable containers with Alpine).

I looked at the Wiki and the website, but couldn't find anything definitive. Does anybody know/have a pointer?

Comment: Hi Andreas, this question seems to be more on-topic on https://unix.stackexchange.com, I suggest you try asking there

Answer (score 0):

The current stable version (3.11 at the time of your mentioned commit, 2020-02-25) generally receives bugfixes. This often also includes feature updates as with CVS 1.11 to 1.12

If you are forced to a specific minor version then you should stick to the last stable version which only receives security-fixes and tries it's best to reduce side-effects.

The current versions with patch policy can be found at: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:Releases